# Change GridView Header Height

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I want to change the height of my GridView, in XAML i use the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"></Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>


    <ListView x:Name="LView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="GView" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}"></GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

But if I want to do this dynamically? I tried:

```
Style style = new Style();
            style.TargetType = typeof(GridViewColumnHeader);
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewColumnHeader.HeightProperty, 155));

            GView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle = style;
```

But I have an ArgumentException (the value 155 is not a valid value). Why? How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I tried you code and did not get an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FrameworkElement.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx) expects a double value so you need to pass 155 as a double with:

```
style.Setters
    .Add(new Setter(GridViewColumnHeader.HeightProperty, 155d));
```

Or

```
style.Setters
    .Add(new Setter(GridViewColumnHeader.HeightProperty, 155.0));
```